# Erro Curl não segue requisição

Tags: php, libcurl, requisição

Estou criando um campo de doações do meu site interligado remotamente com outro porem estou tendo problemas no redirecionamento, envio post datas para a pagina: https://www.kickante.com.br/campanhas/pastor-de-ovelhas/apoiar e oque deveria acontecer é seguir a requisição até o conteúdo da pagina https://www.kickante.com.br/checkout/4242170  mais por algum erro está retornando o código de erro 404 not found meu código aparenta estar correto porem não funciona como deveria funcionar

```html
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
$url = "https://www.kickante.com.br/campanhas/pastor-de-ovelhas/apoiar";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "amount=100%2C00&op=Quero+contribuir%21&form_build_id=form-PNMhiIetNqWfqwL6oc1EtvA_5sG3-J3KEErIg_5Y30o");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
unset($ch);

?>
```

Comment: Tenta capturar o erro da requisição com: if($errno = curl_errno($ch)) {     $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);     echo "cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}"; } assim é possível saber o que esta ocorrendo

Comment: Para isso não precisa usar o `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`?